# DelayCreation & BackgroundCreation are Dosenot Exist in Windows Phone8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

This Code is Working in WP8 But Getting Error in WP8.1 for "DelayCreation &  BackgroundCreation"

```cs
public void SetImageSource(string imagePath)
{
    if (AppSettings.AddNewShowIconVisibility)
    {
       BitmapImage bmImage = BitmapCreateOptions.DelayCreation | BitmapCreateOptions.BackgroundCreation;
    }
}
```

Comment: Only `IgnoreImageCache` is supported on WinRT: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapcreateoptions.aspx

Comment: Then how to use DelayCreation & BackgroundCreation

Comment: Well, you can't, since they're not available

Comment: Then What is the alternative to use DelayCreation & BackgroundCreation